# Updating missing letters in hangman game

Tags: python, set

I'm making a hangman game and have found a problem with my methodology for updating the answer. I have a variable that adds underscores equal to the amount of letters in the word the player needs to guess. However I can't figure out how to effectively update that when the player guesses a correct letter.

Here is my code

```
import random
'''
HANGMAN IMAGE

print(" _________     ")
print("|         |    ")
print("|         0    ")
print("|        /|\\  ")
print("|        / \\  ")
print("|              ")
print("|              ")
'''

def game():
    print('''Welcome to hangman, you must guess letters to fill in the word.
Incorrect guesses will use up a turn, you have 7 turns before you lose.''')
    lines = open("wordBank.txt").read() 
    line = lines[0:] 

    words = line.split() 
    myword = random.choice(words).lower()
    letters = len(myword)
    print("Your word has " + str(letters) + " letters.")

    underscores = ""
    for x in range(0, letters):
        underscores += "_ "
    print(underscores)
    print(myword)
    l = set(myword)
    turn = 0
    guesses = []
    def guess():
        thisGuess = input("Type a letter and press Enter(Return) to guess: ")
        if thisGuess.lower() in l:

        else:
            print("Boo")

    guess()
game()
```

Comment: What have you tried already? While asking for help with homework is allowed, you should set a high standard for yourself before posting a question. Try at least searching a bit first (hangman is a common assignment so there are lots of questions about it already some of which probably provide solutions to this part of the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hangman).

Comment: @acrosman I did take a look at a few and this actually isn't a homework assignment, I'm challenging myself to a list of 101 Programming Projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible approach (in Python 2.7, see below for 3):

```
trueword = "shipping"
guesses = ""

def progress():
    for i in range(len(trueword)):
        if trueword[i] in guesses:
            print trueword[i],
        else:
            print "-",
    print ""
```

This works by checking for each letter if it's been guessed `in guesses`, and printing that letter. If it hasn't been guessed, it prints `-`. When you put a comma at the end of a print (as in `print "-",`) it won't automatically print a newline, so you can continue printing on the same line. `print ""` prints a null string with a newline, finishing the line.

Then guessing becomes:

```
guesses += guess
```

Output is:

guesses = `''`

```
- - - - - - - -
```

guesses = `'sip'`

```
s - i p p i - -
```

---

In Python 3:

```
trueword = "shipping"
guesses = ""

def progress():
    for i in range(len(trueword)):
        if trueword[i] in guesses:
            print(trueword[i], end='')
        else:
            print("-", end='')
    print('')
```

you add the `end=''` parameter to remove the newline, instead of the comma. If you want the spaces between them, you can add `sep=' '` as well to specify the separator.

---

Also, because list comprehensions are awesome (and this works in 2.7 & 3):

```
def progress():
    ans = [word[x] if word[x] in guesses else '-' for x in range(len(word))]
    print(' '.join(ans))
```

Does the same thing via [list comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)... which are a very strong feature in python.

Comment: Much cleaner than mine and easy to understand. Good answer

Comment: I'm in python 3 and I edited your code to work in it but it still makes new lines giving me an output on multiple lines

Comment: @Shniper I added what should work in Python 3, but didn't test it. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Shniper I would encourage you to learn how list comprehensions work, via the last bit. It does the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to reword your question as it's not clear what you are asking.  But you should look into string splicing.  If they guessed the letter "a" and it goes in the third slot then you could do something like

```
underscores[:2] + 'a' + underscores[3:]
```

adapt for your code but that would replace the 3rd underscore with an "a".

UPDATE:
don't use a set, look up the index as you go.  Try something like this

```
for index, letter in enumerate(my_word):
  if letter == guessed_letter:
    if not index == len(my_word) -1
      underscores = underscores[:index] + letter + underscores[index+1:]
    else:
      underscores = undescores[:-1] + letter
```

Comment: I won't be able to do that using a set though will I? Since it needs to know where the letter appears

Comment: @Shniper Why would you use a set? You won't be able to find the appropriate index of the `thisGuess` in some cases (any word which contains duplicate letters)

Comment: It seemed like the easier solution until I realized it would cause problems with knowing where the letter was.

Comment: i've written into my answer how to deal with the index of the letter

Comment: You could use map with letters in word as keys and underscores or letters as values.

Comment: @bravosierra99 I get this error ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: `underscores[:2] + 'a' + underscores[2:]` should be `underscores[:2] + 'a' + underscores[3:]` It's also relevant that trying to splice the last character's `index+1` will net you an "out of index" without checking for it.

Comment: @shniper I forgot the *enumerate*, my apologies

Comment: @TemporalWolf also correct, my bad, was typing faster than thinking.  Thank you.

Comment: @bravosierra99 I'm not really very advanced in python so you kinda lost me with the if not i thing

Comment: @shniper I meant to type `not index`

Comment: @bravosierra99 still not sure what it's purpose is.